# JQuery Mobile+Phone Gap: index.html file is not opened in Browser but it works fine in iPad simulator

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemented an application using ***`jQuery mobile and phone gap (cordova based application) in iPad`***,

I have implemented all the views and code in **`index.html`** page using jQuery

*`when i execute My xcode project works fine it shows required views in simulator.`*

But

***`when i open my index.html file in browsers it doesn't open / shown the views just a blank screen appears why..?`***

Comment: iphone is case sensitive, simulator is not, already checked that?

Comment: where we bother about case sensitive in inex.html page to open in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have some code that depends on cordova which is failing in a "normal" browser -- check your javascript error logs or post a link to you html/js files.

Generally, the "deviceready" event will only fire on a mobile device, so put code that depends on phonegap/cordova in a document listener such as:

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);
```

and don't put non-phonegap code (such as rendering views) in appReady.

See also:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready

->> Josh W <<-